# Auto Layout issue in UICollectionView Xcode 6.4.1 Swift 1.0

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have used collection view to display products on 4 inches screen but when I am using it on iphone 6 then cell size is fixed according to 4 inches screen and I am unable to resize it, another cell starts appearing partially.

Kindly guide me what to do so that it displays only single cell at a time on screen and to see the next I scroll once and it displays the next and do not scroll till end?

I want it to scroll cell by cell not the entire view.

Comment: any specific reason to why you are not using the latest xcode?

Comment: No nothing specific, is it fixed in xcode 7.1?